LinkageError: Method onCreate overrides final method
Generate Signed App APK used to work flawlessly for an app of mine until... I upgraded Android Studio to 2024.1.1.
It still builds and runs perfectly when generating debug APK. However, when I attempt to generate a release APK, it builds successfully, but when the app is launched on the smartphone, it crashes immediately with this FATAL EXCEPTION:
 java.lang.LinkageError:
 Method void com.me.koalawoes.MyAppActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 overrides final method in class Lcom/me/mylib/core/MyActivity;
 (declaration of 'com.me.koalawoes.MyAppActivity'
  appears in /data/app/~~sHPI9ai93DWU6FOp_edr9A==/com.me.koalawoes-8LbG6dXPeAvMUDEvK-x8jQ==/base.apk)

But...MyActivity's onCreate is not declared final at all:
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

What could I be missing?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463855/4807784  says that "onCreate() is specific method called from the OS when your activity is created so it's called after the constructor of the Activity. You have to assign your final fields before onCreate() is called.". Did you check the possibility of your onCreate attempting to assign a value to final?

Thanks @ripopenid. I tried making non-final any finals used in onCreate(...) (read-only) but that didn't change a thing. I wonder what has changed in Android Studio to 2024.1.1 (Koala) that made it so unpredictable.

Here is how I solved the issue:
In the proguard.cfg of my library (where com/me/mylib/core/MyActivity is), I added the following:
-keepnames class com.me.mylib.core.MyActivity {
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle);
}

I still wonder what in my upgrade process (without changing a single line of code) made Generate Signed App APK rely on this -keepnames requirement for onCreate(...). It used to work without this.
At this point, I can only suspect the update from AGP version 8.4 to AGP version 8.5 which was prompted by the upgrade to AS 2024.1.1. R8 is known to change with AGP, as in the android.enableR8.fullMode=false case when migrating from AGP version 7.0.
Also, I couldn't find anything related in Android Gradle plugin 8.5 release notes.

Is com.me.mylib.core.MyActivity compiled as a separate library with minifyEnabled true, which is then used by the app having com.me.koalawoes.MyAppActivity? If the library is compiled separately, then there are no known subclases of com.me.mylib.core.MyActivity, and therefore it can be made final.

@sgjesse Yes, com.me.mylib.core.MyActivity is compiled as a separate library (module) with minifyEnabled true, which is then used by the app having com.me.koalawoes.MyAppActivity. None of them are final - and this is what baffles me: The error message is misleading. Also, this used to work for ~12 years without the need for the -keepnames fix that I added to proguard.cfg . What, in the changes of AS 2024.1.1 and Proguard 8.7, prompted this?

As com.me.mylib.core.MyActivity is compiled without any subclasses present, and minifyEnabled true, then R8 can decide to make the method final. The keep rule you added is basically marking com.me.mylib.core.MyActivity as an "API" class for subclassing (you might want to include all private and protected methods). Also you should use -keep and not -keepnames.
There was an update to AGP 8.4, which changed handling of libraries (https://issuetracker.google.com/338411137), but as you mentioned this came with AGP 8.5 that is probably not your issue.

What you could be missing is that an Android Studio version upgrade may trigger a chain reaction in the form of AGP version update > R8 version update.
It is unclear what happened in your specific upgrade process but there are numerous reports in which a naive Android Studio upgrade led to significant time waste in an attempt to generate a non-crushable release APK:

Android AGP 8.4 and hilt
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/16rd5o9/tip_upgrading_gradle_to_8x_maybe_add_this_before/?rdt=50920

I initially suspected R8's default value of android.enableR8.fullMode has to do with this, but...
From the R8 FAQ:
In non-compat mode, also called “full mode”, R8 performs more aggressive optimizations, meaning additional ProGuard configuration rules may be required.
Full mode can be enabled by adding android.enableR8.fullMode=true in the gradle.properties file. The main differences compared to R8 compatibility mode are:

The default constructor (<init>()) is not implicitly kept when a
class is kept.
The default constructor (<init>()) is not implicitly
kept for types which are only used with ldc, instanceof or checkcast.
The enclosing classes of fields or methods that are matched by a
-keepclassmembers rule are not implicitly considered to be instantiated. Classes that are only instantiated using reflection
should be kept explicitly with a -keep rule.
Default methods are not implicitly kept as abstract methods.
Attributes (such as Signature)
and annotations are only kept for classes, methods and fields which
are matched by keep rules even when -keepattributes is specified. The
weakest rule that will keep annotations and attributes is
-keep[classmembers],allowshrinking,allowoptimization,allowobfuscation,allowaccessmodification
class-specification Additionally, for attributes describing a
relationship such as InnerClass and EnclosingMethod, non-compat mode
requires both endpoints being kept.
When optimizing or minifying the
SourceFile attribute will always be rewritten to SourceFile unless
-renamesourcefileattribute is used in which case the provided value is used. The original source file name is in the mapping file and
when optimizing or minifying a mapping file is always produced.

Note: android.enableR8.fullMode=true became default in AGP 8.0, not 8.5 and certainly not in 7.0. So this alone cannot explain what you described. Citation: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes

Indeed, setting android.enableR8.fullMode=false in gradle.properties doesn't solve any of the issues I have encountered so far. There must be a different root cause. @sgjesse Any ideas?
